# MVC data-val-required on element besides input (Html.EditorFor)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

In MVC, when I create a model with a property that is "Required" and in the HTML markup I create a EditorFor (input box) for that property that it auto-magically adds the "data-val-required" CSS property and I can style that input box however I please.

Assuming I have a heading before that input box, how would I detect if the editor it is associated with and next to is a required field, so that I can style the heading (make it red or add an asterisk in front of it) instead of the input?

```
<td>Heading I want to style</td>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.requiredfield)</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows:

In model set the `DisplayName` Attribute for property as follows:

```
public class ModelName
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Label Text")]
    public string propertyName { get; set; }
 }
```

Then in view you can add class for your editor label as follows:

```
<td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.propertyName , new { @class= "className" })</td>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.propertyName )</td>
```

The above label will render as follows:

```
<label for="propertyName " class="className">Label Text</label>
```

Thus now you can style you editors label as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for the response but nothing in the label would indicate to me whether or not the model property is required.

Comment: My goal is to bind a heading style to a required model property, so that they can never be out of sync (i.e. a heading saying that a field is required when it is really not)